# How to make the following report using Jasper Reports

Tags: jasper-reports

I collect test results between different locations. I can never predict the amount of locations that I should generate the report for and I need to make a dashboard representing these results. The dashboard should look like this (Assume a tabular structure):

```
                                 Title
                      Report info 1|Report info 2
Conditionally displayed report (info 3) spanning the whole table columns
                      Report info 4|Report info 5
                Blank Cell|Location A|Location B...etc
                Location X|X-A result|X-B result...etc
                Location Y|Y-A result|Y-B resutl...etc
                .
                .
                etc
```

I've read A LOT and after a lot of reading I still don't think I can start making a JR report !
Although, after a while of chasing the solution of doing so using tables, I found that I should use crosstabs instead because tables aren't dynamic enough (i.e. since I can't predict the amount of rows\columns that will need to be displayed). But then after reading the crosstabs section I found that it's purpose is to **summarize** results, like calculate totals, averages, minimum and maximum..etc and still, that's not what I need. I'll have to provide all the results locations on the x\y axis and their results, no SQL will be involved.

Also what data structure would be suitable for that ? A datasource ? A java collection\object passed as a parameter ?

Any idea how can I do that with JR ?
Also a I'm finding JR VERY confusing and complicated. I was very happy to read the freely available ultimate guide and check the demos but that didn't help much, it still looks very complicated !

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you cannot predict the amount of columns, crosstabs are the elements you have to choose. But be aware, that the width of a Jasperreport is static (and like this possibly not optimal for your purposes).
A crosstab will summarize your data only, if you have a column or row label twice, and only if the data is not sorted by the crosstab itself or by your datasource.
According to your description, I would use a report layout like

Title-Band: Title, Infos etc
Summary: Crosstab

You could pass the static title content as parameters into your report, the crosstab content as a datasource (e.g. a bean collection)

Comment: You said "A crosstab will summarize...by your datasource."
I may or may not have repeated columns, actually they aren't repeated usually ! Is JR limited here and cannot produce the report I need ?!
Thanks

Comment: Also which datasource you think is valid for this report ?